# Printing QR Codes with Cordova on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, printing, cordova-plugins

I am looking to add functionality to an existing Cordova-based tablet app that runs on iOS (intention is to allow Android later hence Cordova).

We would like to add the ability for users to print a QR code from the app, we know how to generate it.

I am aware of the various libraries out there such as:

https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

Does anyone have any experience with this and can shed some light on how best to achieve this?

As I understand it we could simply send the appropriate commands to the printer, however it seems to me that this might not be possible due to AirPlay restrictions?

Comment: Why? "Starting with KitKat, most Android devices have print service plugins installed to enable printing using the Google Cloud Print and Google Drive services."

Comment: This is for remote workers that will likely be utilizing 3G/4G and so won't have access to a networked printer. Also what you have mentioned relates to Android, as I mentioned I am aware of such services for iOS (AirPlay) but I don't believe they are a solution in this instance.